# Print int numpy array with distance

Tags: numpy, int, pretty-print

I would like to print int `numpy.ndrray` with certain distance between elements. For example, for

```
a = np.array([2, 0, -1, -5, 3, 4])
print('a : {}'.format(a))
```

I have `a : [ 2  0 -1 -5  3  4]`

How can I get, for example `a : [   2    0   -1   -5    3    4]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with formatting.

```
a = np.array([2, 0, -1, -5, 3, 4])
print(("a :" + " {:>3}"*len(a)).format(*a))
a :   2   0  -1  -5   3   4
```

The trick is to keep fixed portions separate, then replicate the {} portion by the number of elements in the array.  The *a will pass on the necessary elements to the format string.
If you really need the square braces it just gets a bit uglier.

```
print(("a : [" + " {:>3}"*len(a) + "]").format(*a))
a : [   2   0  -1  -5   3   4]
```